# Is it okay for a command to slurp more arguments than it is passed to?

Tags: macros, best-practices

Is it okay for a control sequence `\foo` to include another control sequence `\slurp` which slurps more arguments than `\foo` actually passes to it?

For example, is it okay to do this:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand\foo  [1]{#1 \slurp}    
\newcommand\slurp[3]{#1 #2 #3}

\begin{document}
\foo{a}{b}{c}{d}
\end{document}
```

Instead of this?

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand\foo  [4]{#1 \slurp{#2}{#3}{#4}}    
\newcommand\slurp[3]{#1 #2 #3}

\begin{document}
\foo{a}{b}{c}{d}
\end{document}
```

Comment: It's a usual practice: take for example the definition of `\captionof` in the `capt-of` package: `\newcommand\captionof[1]{\def\@captype{#1}\caption}`.

Comment: Every macro that has a starred version or an optional argument works this way. Even `\newcommand` itself is strictly speaking a macro without arguments.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Is this okay? Yes indeed! In fact, there is an abundance of usages for such macro definitions. Most notably the fundamental definitions for starred variants of commands. For example, [`article`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/unpacked/article.cls) defines `\section` as

```
\newcommand\section{\@startsection {section}{1}{\z@}%
                                   {-3.5ex \@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%
                                   {2.3ex \@plus.2ex}%
                                   {\normalfont\Large\bfseries}}
```

See how it takes *zero* arguments, even though we typically specify/use it as `\section[<toc>]{<title>}`?! That is because `\@startsection` takes 6 arguments, and then does a test to see whether the user added a star or not. From [`latex.ltx`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/unpacked/latex.ltx):

```
\def\@startsection#1#2#3#4#5#6{%
  \if@noskipsec \leavevmode \fi
  \par
  \@tempskipa #4\relax
  \@afterindenttrue
  \ifdim \@tempskipa <\z@
    \@tempskipa -\@tempskipa \@afterindentfalse
  \fi
  \if@nobreak
    \everypar{}%
  \else
    \addpenalty\@secpenalty\addvspace\@tempskipa
  \fi
  \@ifstar
    {\@ssect{#3}{#4}{#5}{#6}}%
    {\@dblarg{\@sect{#1}{#2}{#3}{#4}{#5}{#6}}}}
```

As such, the arguments we typically specify for `\section` is only gobbled by a macro two stages down the road.

Another good example of why this is good practice has to do with changes in category codes. Once arguments are consumed for use, their category codes are not changeable. So, a helper macro is usually used to modify the category codes *before* gobbling any arguments.

There are numerous other examples in the [LaTeX kernel](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/unpacked/latex.ltx), from basic font macros to dealing with the ToC, even to defining a new command via `\newcommand`:

```
\def\newcommand{\@star@or@long\new@command}
```

Again, another macro that doesn't take any argument, but performs some operation prior to passing the torch to another macro. In general, this principle is well-used throughout the kernel and packages.

Comment: But what if the helper macro changes so that now it takes one more argument than before? Wouldn't that be a problem if the "helped" macro didn't reflect that change?

Comment: @nicolai.rostov: Yes, if the helper macro now gobbles an additional argument while subsequent macros still require the same amount, you have to update the helper macro to pass the gobbled argument on. However, for the macro-writers, making a chance to a helper macro comes with the consequence of making updates throughout. That's why certain packages that have been around for very long isn't just updated in terms of its interface; things are kept as-is to avoid making things that formerly worked now crash...

Comment: @Wernes: I would then have to update the helped, not the helper, macro. Right?

Comment: @nicolai.rostov: You would have to update whatever is affected. I'm not entirely sure about the context though. If this is just *your* set of macros, then you can update things as you wish. If this deals with a package, then you have to put in some forethought as to the helper macros and how things fit together so that things could remain unchanged.

Comment: Very constructive discussion

Comment: What are the disadvantages of doing this?  Does this break etoolbox patching for example?

Comment: @RichardHansen: Not at all. If [`etoolbox`](http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox) is unable to patch a command, it does not have anything to do with the number of arguments. Instead it has to do with the type of arguments (how they are specified) and perhaps whether the command is robust or not. Ways around this is either through [`xpatch`](http://ctan.org/pkg/xpatch) or via a complete redefinition of the source. In short, I don't see a disadvantage with having a different number of arguments that is "slurped" up.

Comment: This is interesting, but I would love to know how SE came up with this as a possible been-asked-before when I was drafting https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/701864/. Is there some mysterious connection to which mere mortals are not privvy?

Answer (score 10):

As explained in Werner's answer, this is common practice. All macros having a *-variant are defined in this way:

```
\newcommand{\foo}{\@ifstar{\@sfoo}{\@foo}}
\newcommand{\@sfoo}[1]{Foo with * applied to #1}
\newcommand{\@sfoo}[1]{Foo without * applied to #1}
```

or variants thereof. Similarly, macros having more than one optional argument, such as `\makebox` must take a long route for deciding whether there are no, one or two optional arguments:

```
\newcommand{\bar}{\@ifnextchar[{\@bar@i}{\@bar}}
\def\@bar@i[#1]{\@ifnextchar[{\@bar@ii{#1}}{\@bar@iii{#1}}
\def\@bar@ii#1[#2]#3{Bar has two optional arguments, #1 and #2, and #3}
\def\@bar@iii#1#2{Bar has one optional argument, #1, and #2}
\def\@bar#1{Bar has no optional argument and #1}
```

With `xparse` the situation is quite different: since *-variants and optional arguments can be specified in a fairly general way, it's preferred to load *all* actual arguments:

```
\usepackage{xparse}
\NewDocumentCommand{\foo}{sm}{%
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}
    {Foo with * applied to #2}
    {Foo without * applied to #2}%
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\bar}{oom}{%
  \IfNoValueTF{#1}
    {Bar has no optional argument and #3}
    {\IfNoValueTF{#2}
       {Bar has one optional argument, #1, and #3}
       {Bar has two optional arguments, #1 and #2, and #3}%
    }%
  }%
}
```

This is "the future" with LaTeX3.

Comment: So, are you saying people will have to drop the common practice with LaTeX3?

Comment: @nicolai.rostov At the 'document' level yes as it tends to make it hard to see what the 'true' nature of a command is. For code internals there can be advantages to it (it's faster and can read more cleanly in some cases).

Comment: Also, if you use `\show` to reveal what `\NewDocumentCommand` is doing under the hood, you'll discover that `\foo` and `\bar` are zero-argument wrapper macros that invoke various internal-to-`xparse` helpers to process the argument list, and then feed the processed args to `\foo code` / `\bar code` (with the space, yes) which always take the total possible number of arguments.  So it's the same technique, just automated and systematized relative to what was done by hand in the 2e kernel.

Comment: @Zack Right. But the user doesn't need to know. `;-)`