# Is it possible to access the cached value of \pgfarrowlength rather than recalculating it for purposes other than reusing an arrow tip in PGF/TikZ?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows, pgfmath

Is it possible to access the cached value of `\pgfarrowlength` rather than recalculating it for purposes other than reusing an arrow tip in PGF/Ti*k*Z?

---

I am trying to calculate the width (i.e. length) of a Ti*k*Z line less the width required for any arrow tips and/or line caps. I know the height of the line is `\prawfht` and the depth is 0pt. The total line width is `\prawfwd`.

Ideally, I would be able to determine this entirely abstractly i.e. without knowing anything further. However, if necessary, I can insist on knowing the specification e.g. `-TriangularCap` or whatever.

Where I have something like `-{TriangularCap[length=#1]}` or `-{TriangularCap[length=10mm]} this is obviously straightforward, but when tips are used with their default settings, things get complicated. So, it seems I need something like the following:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\newdimen \prawfwd
\newdimen \prawfht
\newdimen \prawfwdadj
\prawfwd=120mm
\prawfwdadj=120mm
\prawfht=10pt
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw [help lines] (0,-3) grid (12,3);
  \coordinate (o) at (0,0);
  \coordinate (e) at (\prawfwd,0pt);
  \begin{scope}[line width=\prawfht]
    \pgfmathsetlength \prawfwdadj {\prawfwd-(3.99365pt+5.391538\prawfht)}
    \draw [Circle-Computer Modern Rightarrow] ([yshift=20mm]o) -- ([yshift=20mm]e);
    \draw  (2.39365pt+3.191538\prawfht,10mm) -- ++(\prawfwdadj,0pt);
    \pgfmathsetlength \prawfwdadj {\prawfwd-(3pt+5.5\prawfht)}
    \draw [Bar-Latex] (o) -- (e);
    \draw  (\prawfht,-10mm) -- ++(\prawfwdadj,0pt);
  \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: lines and arrowed lines]

This produces the correct result, but depends on looking up the default settings for each arrow tip, itself the sum of a base dimension and a multiple of `\prawfht`, and combining them in the case of double-tipped lines.

If a line uses `double`, things get even more interesting.

I know that pgf has just calculated the length of the arrow tip(s) in order to draw them. This is set to `\pgfarrowlength`, I believe, in the code which sets up the tip ready to be drawn. Clearly, this is highly local. For example, for an asymmetric double-tipped line, it has one value when drawing the tip at the start of the line and another when drawing the one at the end.

But I also know `\the\pgfarrowlength` is among the parameters cached for later use, so that it need not be recalculated if the same tip is reused with the same settings. So *pgf* has saved the value of the dimension I need precisely so it need not be recalculated.

Is it possible to access this value directly so I can avoid recalculating it, too?